# can i set checked or unchecked checkbox reading a string value?

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have a string $str that should value 1 or 0 and a checkbox. When i read the string value i want to set the checkbox checked if $str value is 1 or unchecked if $str value is 0.

```
<?
    if ($str == 1){
        // checkbox checked                                                     
    } else {
        // checkbox unchecked                                                           
    }
?>  
<input type='checkbox' name='nome_posiz[]' />
```

Comment: Everything you need about the html attributes to check a checkbox can be found in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a simple documentation answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be

```
$tst = '1';
$chk = $tst=='1' ? "checked='checked'" : '';
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='nome_posiz[]' $chk />";
```

RESULT

```
<input type='checkbox' name='nome_posiz[]' checked='checked' />
```